# Can a primary key contain spaces in a database table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

The DBMS I am working on is SQLite

Can the primary key contain a space?   For example, is it ok to save `Chuck Norris Rules` as a primary key? Or do you recommend changing it to `Chuck_Norris_Rules`?

Can it contain things such as a question mark, exclamation mark, and so on?

For example

Is `Chuck Norris Rules?` acceptable?

Thanks

Comment: You can have spaces in column names - but if you actually intend on using the database and retaining your sanity, you really shouldn't.

Comment: It can but not a best Practice

Comment: Yes, Primary Key can have spaces. I won't do it. Personal habit

Comment: Are you talking about the name of a column or sample data in the column? Because it complicates things to have spaces in the column names (I wouldn't do it), but as a string, the values could be anything, including strings with spaces.

Comment: A space is just another character in a column's value. There is nothing special about spaces in database values (from the database point of view). So the answer is: yes, absolutely. There is no difference between the primary key `Artur Dent` and `abcdefg` as far as the DB is concerned.

Comment: You might want to avoid spaces, as well as using reserve words as it will make it easier for you to deal with if this is a serious project.

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF: the question isn't about spaces in the column *name*, it's about spaces in the column *value*

Comment: @KershawRocks Do your mean as the name of the column or index and such? Or do you mean as values in the column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primary key can contain *anything*:

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> create table t(pk primary key);
sqlite> insert into t values(null);
sqlite> insert into t values(1);                -- integer
sqlite> insert into t values(2.34);             -- real
sqlite> insert into t values('Hello, world!');  -- text
sqlite> insert into t values(x'f09f98bb');      -- blob
sqlite> select * from t;

1
2.34
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Can't contain spaces before or after content.